# Cannot install nlopt python module

Tags: python, macos, nlopt

I am trying to install nlopt onto macOS 10.15.5. I downloaded the [nlopt-2.6.2.tar.gz file](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/files/4866514/nlopt-2.6.2.tar.gz) from the [NLopt docs](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and ran the following from the nlopt-2.6.2 directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DNLOPT_OCTAVE=Off -DNLOPT_MATLAB=Off -DNLOPT_GUILE=Off ..
make
sudo make install
```

I got the following output: [cmake.txt](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/files/4866503/cmake.txt).

The header file (`nlopt.h`) installs correctly to `/usr/local/include` and the dynamic library (`libnlopt.dylib`) installs correctly to `/usr/local/lib/`, but neither the dist-info file nor the nlopt module itself installs.

I have also tried installing via pip, brew, and conda, none of which have worked. I have also tried cloning from this Github, which didn't work either.

I appreciate any help with this, because I am completely lost. I am relatively new to this kind of stuff, and I couldn't find any good answers online.

Comment: Looking at your output, it does look like `libnlopt.dylib` installs. Is there an error message that you are receiving that might help?

Comment: @C.Nivs: Thanks for your reply. You are right I was able to find `libnlopt.dylib` under `/usr/local/lib/` I will edit my original question accordingly. Unfortunately, I don't receive any error messages.

Answer (score 3):

The official docs are somewhat laconic about the exact steps required for building `nlopt` with Python bindings. First of all, you'll need SWIG installed:

```
$ brew install swig
```

Then, you'll need `numpy` to be available for the target Python interpreter. It is already preinstalled for the system Python, otherwise install it via Homebrew or `pip`, depending on your Python installation.

Now run `cmake`:

```
$ cmake -DNLOPT_GUILE=OFF -DNLOPT_MATLAB=OFF -DNLOPT_OCTAVE=OFF -DNLOPT_TESTS=OFF
```

This will build bindings against the default Python 2.7 installation preinstalled on MacOS. If you need to build against custom Python installation (e.g. when you've installed Python 3 via Homebrew or PKG installer from https://www.python.org/downloads), pass it via the `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` arg:

```
$ cmake -DNLOPT_GUILE=OFF -DNLOPT_MATLAB=OFF -DNLOPT_OCTAVE=OFF -DNLOPT_TESTS=OFF -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Inspect the log now - Python, SWIG and `numpy` headers should be successfully located. Example output snippet (you may have different paths/versions printed):

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 (found version "3.8.3")
-- Found PythonLibs: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib (found suitable exact version "3.8.3")
-- Found NumPy: /Users/hoefling/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include (found version "1.19")
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "4.0.2")
```

If any of those conditions is not satisfied (e.g. you see `Could NOT find NumPy`,  `Could NOT find PythonLibs` or `Could NOT find SWIG`), then stop and make sure the configuration succeeds before proceeding next.

Now compile:

```
$ make
...
Scanning dependencies of target nlopt_python_swig_compilation
[ 96%] Swig compile nlopt.i for python
[ 96%] Built target nlopt_python_swig_compilation
Scanning dependencies of target nlopt_python
[ 98%] Building CXX object src/swig/CMakeFiles/nlopt_python.dir/CMakeFiles/nlopt_python.dir/nloptPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module _nlopt.so
[100%] Built target nlopt_python
```

Install:

```
$ make install
...
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nlopt.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_nlopt.so
```

Test the Python bindings are importable:

```
$ python -c "import nlopt; print(nlopt.__version__)"
2.6.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Turns out `swig 4.0.2 is already installed, it's just not linked`. I have now linked swig but nlopt still won't install. One question for you: Running `make install` returns an error that says `CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:40 (file): file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/local/include/nlopt.h": Operation not permitted.` so I am running `sudo make install` instead. Does this make a difference/why does `make install` return an error?